# How to display comments and comment form on custom post type?

Tags: posts, forms, comments, customization

Is it possible in wordpress to display comments and comment form on custom post type, and how to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comments not showing in custom post type - Wordpress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29866/comments-not-showing-in-custom-post-type-wordpress)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1)** add "comments" to the supports array when registering the post type.

[image: Register Post Type]

**2)** add the comments_template() function inside the loop of the single.php template and you are good to go.

[image: Add Comment Template To Post]

Comment: `<?php if (is_single ()) comments_template (); ?>`

Comment: I need Woocommerce wishlist to extend with comment feature, the wishlist  post type registering in `wp-content\plugins\woocommerce-wishlists\woocommerce-wishlists.php` so in such case how do we enable comments?